# Split an array of strings based on character

Tags: c

I have an array of strings similar to this:

```
char* arrStrings[] = {"a", "be", "|", "cgg", "dss", "|", "mmd", "ddd", "\0"}
```

1) I would like to be able to be able to split this into a set of arrays, based on where the '|' character is.

So, after splitting, I would have this:

```
a1 = {"a", "be", "\0"}
a2 = {"cgg", "dss", "\0"}
a3 = {"mmd", "ddd", "\0"}
```

2) After that, I need to create a linked list that has all 3 arrays, like this:

```
list = {pointer to a1, pointer to a2, pointer to a3}
```

I'm very confused about it, since there are multiple levels of pointers involved. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: tipo: `'` => `"`? What do you try?

Comment: if it is array of strings all elements should be "{element}".

Comment: You can accomplish this by writing code. At present, it seems that you are asking others to do it for you, which is somewhat problematic considering the rules of this website. You are generally expected to show your work, and then explain where you got stuck, what problems you're experiencing, etc.

Comment: I found other questions similar to this one, where no code was submitted. I just don't understand the levels of pointers that are involved and I'm asking for guidance as to how those would look.

For 1) I know how to loop through until I find the character '|', but I don't know how to create a new array with all the strings before that.

For 2) I don't know how to define the node for my linked list, whether that is char *** or char **.

Comment: Are you sure you need step 1? Where does the data come from and where is it going?

Comment: The data is coming from a function that's been provided to me that simply parses through a line and returns a char ** structure. I'm trying to parse this structure into a linked list of arrays that I can pass to another function to work with each array separately.

I'm using this as part of a bigger task of creating a simple linux shell in C. Each element of the linked list (an array of strings) is a command that I will pass to a function to execute.

Comment: What do you call *a linked list* in C? A mere array, a custom struct, a particular library?

Comment: It would just be a custom struct.

Comment: Without knowing the linked list API, I cannot use it to provide a solution...

Comment: It would look something like this typedef struct node {
    char *** commandArray;
    struct node * next;
} node_t;

Comment: I'm not too sure about the char *** commandArray part. This would a pointer to an array of strings.

Comment: Actually it would be char ** instead.

Comment: Hints: a pointer to string and pointer to array (or sub-array) or strings are all `char **` that is the value of your node struct. Just iterate the original string putting each and every start of sub array in a node allocated via malloc. Be cautious for first and last node and it should work. Write some code,test it and edit the question with it if you are still stuck.

Comment: We need to see what you have done so far in order to help.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use `NULL` as delimiter in the list, you don't need to duplicate the strings, just use an array of pointers to string.

```
*arrStrings[] = {"a", "be", "|", "cgg", "dss", "|", "mmd", "ddd", ""};
```

is transformed into

```
*arr       [] = {"a", "be", NULL, "cgg", "dss", NULL, "mmd", "ddd", NULL};
```

Once you have filled the array you can use an array of pointers to pointer to string to create the list:

```
*arr       [] = {"a", "be", NULL, "cgg", "dss", NULL, "mmd", "ddd", NULL};
**ptr      [] = { ^                 ^                   ^               };
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    /* The array */
    char *arrStrings[] = {"a", "be", "|", "cgg", "dss", "|", "mmd", "ddd", ""};
    /* Elements of the array */
    size_t sz = sizeof(arrStrings) / sizeof(arrStrings[0]);
    /* Loop */
    size_t i, n = 0;
    /* Create an array (VLA) of n pointers */
    char *arr[sz];

    /* Count the number of delimiters and fill array */
    for (i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        /* If we found a delimiter assign NULL */
        if (strcmp(arrStrings[i], "|") == 0) {
            arr[i] = NULL;
            n++;
        } else
        /* If we found an empty string assign NULL */
        if (arrStrings[i][0] == '\0') {
            arr[i] = NULL;
        } else {
            arr[i] = arrStrings[i];
        }
    }
    /* Create an array (VLA) of n delimiters pointers to pointer */
    char **ptr[n + 1];
    ptr[0] = &arr[0];
    for (i = n = 0; i < sz - 1; i++) {
        /* For each NULL string push address of array + 1 into ptr */
        if (arr[i] == NULL) {
            ptr[++n] = &arr[i + 1];
        }
    }
    /* For each pointer to pointer loop and print until NULL */
    char **str;
    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        str = ptr[i];
        printf("%zu)\n", i);
        while (*str != NULL) {
            printf("\t%s\n", *str);
            str++;
        } 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0)
    a
    be
1)
    cgg
    dss
2)
    mmd
    ddd
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you have to know is that an array of strings is a pointer to a fixed number of further pointers to characters

```
arrString --> |_|_|_| ... |_|
               | | |       |
               V V V       V
               a b |       \0
                 e
```

therefore you cannot simply update the "|" element with "\0" and manage the string as it would be the "strtok" function for example. Rather, you have to allocate three new "char**" array to maintain the three "char*" sequences, and use them to create the list as you prefer.

In case you want to avoid the allocation of new memory space, then you have to implement customized facilities, in order to parse the "char**" array according to its formatting. In this way you can really have three pointers to three different positions in "arrString", which define the first sub-string that belongs to the interested array. The final element "|" or "\0" will indicate no further elements belong to it. However, as I already said, this requires you implement ad-hoc functions, which avoid to alter the array.